# I can't define an element into my char array

Tags: arrays, c, string, char

I'm study for work with C. I have a code like this:

```
int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    char usernames[8][20] = {"Lebron","Gasol","Davis","Schroder","KCP","Jr Smith"};
    int i =0;
    usernames[6][20] = 'Danny';
    fp=fopen("out.txt","w");
    for(i=0; i<7; i++) {
        fprintf(fp,"%s\n",usernames[i]);
    }
}
```

In my text file, "Danny" is not written. Can't I add an element like 3rd line? How can I add an element to my array after I defined it?

Comment: Note that the `20` in `usernames[6][20]` is not a valid array subscript — it is an array bounds violation.  The elements go from 0 to 19.  Note too that `'Danny'` is an implementation-defined multi-character constant, not a string.

Comment: In general `char a[n]; a[n] = x` is attempting to write out of bounds.  When you assign to `usernames[6][20]` you invoke undefined behavior by writing beyond the bounds of the array.  And `'Danny'` is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 3):

Check the data type!

`usernames[6][20]` is of type `char`, and `'Danny'` is not a `char` type (not the use of single quotes `''`). Your compiler should have warned you sometjing along the lines of

```
warning: character constant too long for its type
     usernames[6][20] = 'Danny';
                        ^~~~~~~
warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
```

Turn up the compiler warnings.

You need to copy a string, so you should use `strcpy()`, like

```
 strcpy(usernames[6], "Danny");
```